# How to solve this linker input file unused and linking not done in Eclipse ide?

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, linker, pthreads

I created a memory linker script and saved it as memory.ld in the eclipse ide :
Project : properties : gcc linker : miscellaneous : I added -M -T memory.ld

memory.ld :

```
MEMORY
{
        MYMEMORY(rw)   : ORIGIN = 0x40000000 ,  LENGTH = 30  
}

.myvarloc (NOLOAD):
{
  *(.myvarloc)

} > MYMEMORY
```

In my c program : I made a global declaration as:

```
__attribute__ ((section(".myvarloc")))
uint8 measurements[30];
```

After running my project, it is displaying as:
linker input file unused because linking not done

how to solve the above problem ??

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the diagnostic containing `linker input file unused because linking not done`
I believe you will see that it refers to one of your object files, not to the linker script.

Linkage is not done because you are passing the options `-M -T memory.ld` to
gcc for the linkage step. But `-M` is not a linker option, it is a preprocessor
option; so gcc (which is a driver program for selecting and invoking the appropriate tools) infers that it is to perform a preprocessing step, not a linkage.

To correct this, remove `-M` from the miscellaneous linker options and add it to
the miscellaneous compiler options.

In addition, make sure that your linker script option is like:

```
-T relative/path/to/memory.ld
```

where `relative/path/to/memory.ld` correctly locates `memory.ld` relative
to the current *build* directory of the project. E.g. if you saved `memory.ld` in
`MyProject/src` and are performing a debug build, then the build directory
will be `MyProject/Debug` and your linker script option will be `-T ../src/memory.ld`

Comment: I added -M to the end of the existing compiler options like this :     -c -fmessage-length=0 -M and later I rebuild it but it showing error as :  cannot open linker script file memory.ld: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Did not understand sir.

Comment: Are you running on Linux?

Comment: I am running on linux operating system

Comment: OK, just do this. Your Eclipse project is in a directory `MyProject`
somewhere under your home directory. Look in it/under it and find where you have saved `memory.ld`. If you have saved it as `MyProject/memory.ld` just leave it there. If it is somewhere else then move it to `MyProject/memory.ld`, Then set your linker script option as `-T ../memory.ld`. Then the link step will find it, because when the linker runs its working directory is `MyProject/Debug` (for a debug build) or `MyProject/Release` (for a release build).

Comment: memory.ld is saved in home/user/workspace/linux/memory.ld : So I added -T ../linux/memory.ld. Is it right ??

Comment: Probably not. In the Eclipse IDE, in the **Project explorer** window, right-click on the name of your project. From the menu select **Properties**. Select **Resource** in the tree-view. On the **Properties for YourProject : Resource** page, find **Location**. What is the location?

Comment: Are you quite sure that the project location was `/home/user/workspace/LINUX` and not e.g. `/home/user/workspace/LINUX/YourProjectName`?

Comment: I am sure about the project location and the project name is LINUX only. LINUX project contains so many sub folders and files in it.

Comment: In the Eclipse IDE, look at at your project (LINUX) -> **Properties** -> **C/C++ build** -> **Environment**. You will see a variable setting for `CWD`. It is a directory name, say, `/path/to/project/build/dir`.  Your `-T relative/path/to/memory.ld` option must replace `relative/path/to` with a relative path that lets the file be found when the current directory is
`/path/to/project/build/dir`. Sorry but I can't help you any more than this.